# "this" undefined in React component event handler

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

When the user clicked submit button I need to bind these input fields to an instance of Message interface, to do this I created an Message object in class
and set the values of input values in form(keepNameUpdated()).

When I type something it throws

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

so it says "this" is undefined, but why?

here is my code:

```
     export class IMessage {
          Name: string;
          Surname: string;
        }



     export default class Contact extends React.Component<IContactProperties, IWebPartState> {
        message : IMessage;
        constructor(props: IContactProperties, state: IWebPartState) {
            super(props);
            this.message = new IMessage();
        }
 public render(): JSX.Element {
            return (
                 <div className="row">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label >Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.keepNameUpdated} id="name" placeholder="Adiniz" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label >Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Soyadiniz" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.clickSubmit}><i className="fa fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                );
    }

        private keepNameUpdated(e) {
            this.message.Name=e.target.value;
          }
          private keepSurnameUpdated(e) {
            this.message.Surname=e.target.value;
          }
```

why this reference is undefined ?
[image]

Comment: bits of the code are missing. where's the render function?

Comment: I am tring to make it simple, this return jsx elements method actualy belongs to render function

Comment: Better complete than incomplete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you have to bind the handler functions so that their notion of `this` refers to the instance of the React component. So, in your constructor, add these lines:

`this.keepNameUpdated = this.keepNameUpdated.bind(this);
this.keepSurnameUpdated = this.keepSurnameUpdated.bind(this);`

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Yes it looks solved my problem but why I have to specify it explicitly ? what if I have 100 property ?

Comment: This is just the way event handlers work in javascript and browser DOMs. I don't know React well enough to help you out, but perhaps there are some helper functions in the framework that will do the work for you... Read more documentation :)